# Filter values from two objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Ok so this might seem simple, but somehow I am not getting the desired result here.
I have two objects like this:

```
const parentObj = { a: "true", b: "true", c: "true", d: "true", e: "true" }
const childObj = { b : "true", e: "true" }
```

I want to compare these two objects, find common keys, and assign the value of common key from `childObj` to `parentObj`, so that I get the result:

```
{ a: "false", b: "true", c: "false", d: "false", e: "true" }
```

I tried this, but it's not working.

```
for (const parent in parentObj) {
    let valueFound = false;
    for (const child in childObj) {
        if (parent === child) {
            if (child === true) {
                parentObj[parent] = true;
                valueFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!valueFound) {
        parentObj[parent] = false;
    }
}
```

What's wrong here and what's the proper solution?

Comment: Whats `value` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms: That was a typo. My actual code has nested object, and while copying it here, I missed to omit it. Have corrected it now.

Comment: Doesn't make things better. Thats stil the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code *does work*, if you replace `child === true` (which makes little sense as `child` is a key [string]) with `childObj[child] === true`. Or compare against `"true"` if you really want these booleans as strings. But your solution is quite slow, there is no need to iterate over the `childObj` and its keys, as you can just look up:

```
  for(let key in parentObj)
    parentObj[key] = childObj[key] === "true" ? "true" : "false";
```

Comment: This seems smart but doesn't work as the value assigned to `parentObj[key]` becomes a string like `"true"` rather than a boolean `true`. Will work if I add `Boolean` like this `parentObj[key] = Boolean(childObj[key]) || false;`

Comment: Then the objects aren't exactly the way you've shown it. I can't write code for data I don't see ...

Comment: As a sidenote `Boolean("false")` evaluates to `true`, just saying. If its really a string, you wanna do `childObj[key] === "true"`

Comment: The object values in my code are string, not boolean. Have corrected the same in the question. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: And why? Is there any reason?

Comment: I didn't write the app. It's an existing application I am working on.

Comment: `git blame`, just saying. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` method:

```
  const parentObj = { a: true, b: false, c: true, d: true, e: false };
  const childObj = { b : true, e: true };

  const mergedObj =  Object.assign({}, parentObj, childObj);
  for (let key in mergedObj){
  if ( !childObj[key])
      mergedObj[key] = false;
  }

  console.log(mergedObj );
```

UPDATE:

Your code can be shortened. There is no need for the second loop. Because objects are dictionaries and you can always get  `O(N)`:

```
for (const parent in parentObj) {
    if ( child[parent])
        child[parent] = parentObj[parent];
    else    
        parentObj[parent] = false;    
}
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the result needed.

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for your attention! I've edited my answer. Sorry for hurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
let parentObject = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  c: true // not changed:- because its not present in child
}
let childObject = {
  b: false,
  a: false,
  f: true // ignored:- because its not available in parent
}
for(let cKey in childObject) {
  if(parentObject.hasOwnProperty(cKey)) {
    parentObject[cKey] = childObject[cKey];
  }
}

console.log(parentObject)
```